# Show a menu next to cursor on mouse hover on div

Tags: javascript, html, css, cursor

I have a table on which I want to show a button-group when users hover over the rows. Here is what I know I need.

1. Get mouse location `event.clientX and event.clientY`
2. Show button next to mouse location by changing css properties
3. hide the button-group when user moves away from the table row
   I don't know how to draw the button-group next to my cursor and the button functions are heavily dependent on the row data which I now get by using `this` but if I draw the div, I am not sure if I will be able use `this`.
   Any ideas, suggestions, links will be really appriciated.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the mouse location, you can do this by making use of the CSS :hover property and the 'display: hidden' property.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      table tr button { display: none; float:right }
      table tr:hover button { display:block }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <table border=1 width=300px>
      <tr><td>LINE1 <button>BUTTON1</button></td></tr>
      <tr><td>LINE2 <button>BUTTON2</button></td></tr>
      <tr><td>LINE3 <button>BUTTON3</button></td></tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. I need to have the button right next to my mouse cursor. Almost like a floating menu that follows the cursor around.

Comment: So I fixed the cursor issue

Comment: I fixed the cursor issue. The tooltip renders as well but it is sortof invisible. I suspect its because my full calendar is on a modal. Any suggestions on how to tackle this?

Comment: Could you post a new question and share the code where the issue happens? Or is that part of this same issue (if so, maybe update description)

Comment: Yes ofc. Apologies. Here's the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60484926/tooltip-renders-on-modal-but-stays-hidden